# What is this air-scoop behind the cockpit of the Polikarpov I-153 and Stearman?

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification

[image: P153]
([Source](http://www.fiddlersgreen.net/aircraft/Polikarpov-I-153/IMAGES/3view-Polikarpov-I-153.jpg))

There is a Ferrari-looking air-scoop behind the cockpit of the I-153 and most of the Stearman planes too.

What is that?

Comment: @ymb1 I wasnt (Or werent ?) thinking it would be that bad, I simply copy pasted an "English language object template" and replaced the words

Comment: -1 wrong colour for [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/183280) :-)

Answer (score 9):

[image]
([Source](http://www.formula1-dictionary.net/Images/Scoop_McL1.jpg))

The F1 air-scoop / airbox is well clear of the driver's head to feed air into the engine (the [airbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbox) itself is shaped so that each cylinder gets equal share of air).

In your 3-view diagram, that's a streamlined headrest for drag reduction.

The [I-153 has a top speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polikarpov_I-153#Specifications_(I-153_(M-62))) of 444 km/h (243 knots, 280 mph), whereas such streamlining is not needed for the leisurely paced [Tiger Moth](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:De_Havilland_DH82_Tiger_Moth_DF112_2a_(6115652701).jpg), for example.

Googling photographs makes it clear, unlike that line drawing.

[image]
([Source](https://cdn.airplane-pictures.net/images/uploaded-images/2011/12/10/171698.jpg)) Click to view.

Comment: The windshield should already take care of the pilot's neck. The fairing is mostly for drag reduction.

Comment: The headrest protected the pilot in the case of the plane flipping over in a landing, specially in low-wing monoplanes like the I-16 or the Boeing 'Peashooter'.